# Store the value of split in String[] array without using String.split()

Tags: java

I want to convert below code to store the split string in string array without using String.split() because i am working on legacy java 1.2 in our production environment

```
String strings ="1,2,3,4;5,6,7,8";
String[] output= strings.split(";");
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: You'll have to implement it yourself: loop over the characters of the string, do whatever needs to be done when you find a `;`, etc. (Java 1.2 in production? Wow, that's *old!*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    String strings ="1,2,3,4;5,6,7,8";
    StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(strings, ";,");
    String[] coordinates = new String[tok.countTokens()];

    int j = 0;
    while (tok.hasMoreTokens()) {
        coordinates[j++] = tok.nextToken();
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(coordinates));
```

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

You can specify the delimiters. If you only `;` for instance.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`StringTokenizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html), the javadoc it has been around since version 1.

Just do

```
StringTokenizer strTokenizer = new StringTokenizer("1,2,3,4;5,6,7,8", ";");
```

and iterate while `strTokenizer.hasMoreElements()`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `StringTokenizer` since `StringTokenizer` available since `JDK 1.0`. You better to change your `JDK` in production too.

```
StringTokenizer stringTokenizer=new StringTokenizer("1,2,3,4;5,6,7,8",",;");
String[] arr=new String[stringTokenizer.countTokens()];
int i=0;
while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){
   arr[i]=stringTokenizer.nextToken();
   i++;
}
```

Comment: By declaring String[] arr=new String[8]; unnecessary it will store memory if i required less character also

Comment: @rahularora yes. Then how you going to get `String` array?

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with 1.2 limitations... you may do it manually: first, count the ';' occurences so you can create your coordinates array, then use available `String` methods to go through your original string and concatenate the result and stop every ';'

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Scanner** class for the same purpose.

```
  String s="1,2,3,4;5,6,7,8";
  Scanner sc=new Scanner(s).useDelimiter(";");
while(sc.hasNext())
 {
  System.out.println(sc.next());
 }
```